# Generate pistache server with chosen JSON library in OpenApi

Tags: c++, json, swagger, openapi

I've got full REST API specification yaml file to generate c++ pistache server side code in OpenApi or SWAGGER.

Could I change default nlohmann JSON included library to another in code generation process?

Comment: What code generation tool do you use?

Comment: OpenApi Generator https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator and/or swagger online https://editor.swagger.io

Comment: Is it solved? or else?